# My .gz deliver as css but not being applied to my theme display

Tags: css, wordpress, .htaccess, gzip

I've been using this app to minify my files which works great. 
Link - http://minifyapp.com/

From the app's website I am given the following code to place in my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -f 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.gz [L]
```

However, this code is a little outdated because I noticed the filed weren't coming to the browser as css.

So I've dug around all day trying to fix this and added the following with the above

```
AddEncoding gzip .gz
AddEncoding x-gzip .gz
AddType text/css .gz
AddType text/javascript .gz
AddType text/x-javascript .gz
Header set Content-Encoding "gzip" env=is_gzip
```

This works to enable the browser to understand the .gz files as css.

But, I'm not getting the the content of those .gz files to be actually applied to my theme's styles.

So specifically in my source code I can see my .gz file being referenced instead of my normal .css.

And if I click to view the .gz file in the browser it renders as it should, css instead of a archived file.

But my theme has no actual styles applied to it.

What do you think is the problem and how can I fix it.

I've tested this with plugins and my theme's stylesheets, still the same result.

Comment: Why are you gz'ing your CSS? Just optimize your CSS with an online tool(i.e. remove white space) and then use Apache mod_deflate to send it compressed. Then you won't have to do all of that stuff and cause your theme not to work,.

Comment: Because I've already done all that and I would like to try this and see the results difference. 

I'm not a pro trained dev person, but have learned enough and would like to weigh all my angles by testing them. 

This is all done local so there is no harm done in testing it out. 

This is also carried over from a concept that doing it the above way means the browser each time needs to send it compressed when some of the content doesn't change and there can already be compressed. 

Can you help?